# What is the "Galaxy Specials" category for?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am trying to publish my apps on [Samsung Seller Office](http://seller.samsungapps.com/login/signIn.as?returnURL=%2ferror%2ferrorPage.as%3fgoPage%3dastoreNotPermittedError&ssoCheck=fail). However, first I get an error that I left the Category field blank. The only category available is "Galaxy Specials". When I select it, I get another drop down box with a list of subcategories. I don't use any of the listed features in my app. They all appear to be from the Samsung APIs. I just want to publish the same app as I have on Google Play in order to reach more customers.

So my question is what is the Galaxy Specials category for? Am I right that it is related to the Samsung-specific APIs? If so, what do I do since I don't want to select any of these features?

Comment: Um, this seems like a marketing-related question, not for programming.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there a more appropriate SE site to ask this on?

Comment: I doubt that there is any SE site to ask this on. That doesn't make it appropriate for here, though, as the SE site network isn't aiming to cover all questions. Ideally, you'd ask Samsung, though I realize that getting responses from vendors is sometimes a challenge.